# addEventListener is not a function for matchMedia in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari

I don't have `iOS` with `safari` browser so I cannot test it properly.

Here is my code:

```
if (window && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')) {
        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
          .addEventListener('change', (mediaQuery) => {
            console.log('theme', mediaQuery);
            // ....
          });
      }
```

With that code I'm getting error (in online testing tool):
`window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener is not a function`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is because Safari used to only support the deprecated `MediaQueryList.addListener()`.

Support for `MediaQueryList.addeventlistener()` came in version 14 (Released 2020-09-16).

To support both ways, you can use:

```
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

if (mediaQuery?.addEventListener) {
    mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', handler);
} else {
    mediaQuery.addListener(handler);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The spec only speaks of `addListener` (https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#the-mediaquerylist-interface),  and that is the only function safari has included.

This also has the widest support, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener.

So you're could should become:

```js
if (window && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')) {
        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
          .addListener((mediaQuery) => {
            console.log('theme', mediaQuery);
            // ....
          });
      }
```